# Invalid port number displaying on jenkins Environmental variable

Tags: jenkins, cmd, environment-variables, hudson

When I tried to display the `JENKINS_URL` env variable using batch script. it displaying an incorrect port number.

My Jenkins port number is 8443, But the output from `%JENKINS_URL%` is as

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Is there anything wrong from my side?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `%JENKINS_URL%` comes from global configuration, not actual server address.

Go to **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System**, and look for **Jenkins Location** section